# Sharepoint: hide left (quicklaunch) navigation menu

Tags: sharepoint

how can I hide (**server-side**) the left navigation menu? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I founfd the answer by myself:

```
Master.FindControl("PlaceHolderLeftNavBar").Visible = false;
```